# Converting number in name of gameobject into alpha keycode

Tags: unity, c#

So I have no idea if there is a way to do this, but I'm trying to find a way to turn an alpha number in a game object name string into an Alpha key code, which I'm going to use in an Input.GetKey.
Heres my code:

```cs
string slot = transform.parent.parent.name;
string refinedSlot = slot[11];
KeyCode keySlot = KeyCode.Alpha/*refinedSlot*/;
```

Thanks in advance. I also know that refinedSlot is probably useless, but I added it in case it might be usefull.

Comment: I already know someone is going to ask about this, so I'm just going to say that slot and refinedSlot are strings, and keySlot is a KeyCode.

Comment: Myself, I'd put a component on this object with a `public KeyCode keySlot` field rather than muck about with strings and encoding gameplay data in names.

Comment: I don't want to do anything complicated as I am a beginner, and this is for a hotbar.

Comment: @DanielKim The solution by DMGregory seems less complicated to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `slot` is a `string` then `slot[11]` is one character of this string and is of type `char`.

Fortunately the digits in Unity's [`KeyCode` Enum](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) are backed by the same integer value as the corresponding characters. Therefore, we can simply cast the character to this `KeyCode` enum.

```cs
string slot = transform.parent.parent.name;
char refinedSlot = slot[11];
KeyCode keySlot = (KeyCode)refinedSlot;
```

A safer way to extract the last character of a string (whose exact length needs not to be known) is to use the C# 8.0 [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes) feature. By eliminating the temp variables, we get

```cs
var keySlot = (KeyCode)transform.parent.parent.name[^1];
```

Comment: I don't know what's causing it but it now says "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: @DanielKim Without seeing your project or your code I can only guess, by my best guess would be that `transform.parent.parent.name` is less than 11 characters.

Comment: Is the first character of a name [0] because I set it to 10 and it worked when the name has 11 characters

Comment: For `slot[11]` to work, the strings must at least 12 characters long. Since C# 8.0 / Unity 2020.2 you can use [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes). To get the last character of the string, you can write `slot[^1]`, meaning the first character from the right.